# Linear Differential Equation $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + y\arctan{x} = 5e^{\cos{x}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

Linear Differential equation:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} + y\cdot\arctan(x) = 5e^{\cos(x)}
$$

From this I know that:

$$
P(x) = \arctan(x) \\
F(x) = 5e^{\cos(x)}
$$

Now determining the integrating factor $u$:

$$
u = e^{\int{{\arctan{x}\,dx}}} = e^{-\frac{1}{2} \log{(x^2+1)} + x\arctan{x}} = e^{\log{(x^2+1)}^{-\frac{1}{2}}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}} = {(x^2+1)}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}}
$$

Now in multiplying this by the original equation:

$$
(x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} + (x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}} \cdot y \arctan{x} = (x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}} \cdot 5e^{\cos(x)} \\
 \frac{d((x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}} y)}{dx} = (x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}} \cdot 5e^{\cos{x}} \\
$$

Integrating both sides:

$$
(x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}} y = \int (x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^{x\arctan{x}} \cdot 5e^{\cos{x}}dx 
$$

In which I am having problems with the integral. Where did I go wrong and how do I resolve the the problem?

Comment: Edit your post.

Comment: @thomas-andrews I am trying but it's a bit difficult as I only have my mobile.

Comment: The [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) isn’t the only problem; some of it is just conceptually incoherent, like $\displaystyle\int\frac{\partial(\cdots)}{dx}$, which makes no sense, because you haven’t specified the variable with respect to which the function is being integrated, and you’ve also mixed a total and partial derivative.

Comment: (–1) I’ll be happy to undo my downvote once you make significant revisions (just @ me in a comment).

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong. The final integral just doesn't have a closed form. It's non-elementary.

Comment: For future reference, please put parentheses `( )` around $x^2+1$. Curly braces `{ }` are for formatting and will not show unless you write them as `\{ \}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question — "Where did I go wrong?" — is pretty easy to answer: your integrating factor $u$ is very wrong. Your mistake is that you can't "integrate" like that in the exponent:
$$\int e^{f(x)}\,dx \color{red}{\neq} e^{\int f(x)\,dx}.$$
In other words, while it's true that
$$\int \arctan x\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+1)+x\arctan x+C$$
(which, by the way, you typed incorrectly, as $\ln x^2+1\color{red}{\neq}\ln(x^2+1)$), that does **NOT** make the antiderivative of the exponent what you said it would be:
$$\int e^{\arctan x}\,dx\color{red}{\neq}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+1)+x\arctan x}+C.$$

What to do with it is a whole different question… Where did this question come from? Are you sure you have the correct statement of the equation? I didn't try to integrate it by hand, but Wolfram Mathematica gives a *very ugly* antiderivative of $\int e^{\arctan x}\,dx$.

Comment: If I revised correctly I believed that was a typo and from what you said, the integral is correct, no?

Comment: @OmariCelestine: You correctly revised the notation in the line that starts with $u=\ldots$, even though the same error still persists in the rest of your work. (And this is more than just poor notation, because it creates a mathematically different statement.) But more importantly, you didn't fix your mathematical mathematical mistakes: the notation in that line is now correct (in the sense of being meaningful), but the integral is still wrong.